# How to exclude a page from the navigation tree

Tags: navigation

I am looking for a way to exclude certain pages from the navigation. I know it must be quite easy, but nothing seems to work for me at the moment.

So I've setup a lightswitch field "exclude from navigation" (cf_hideFromNav)

Problem is that I want the navigation to start only from a certain slug:

```
{% set topEntry = craft.entries.section('pages').depth(1).slug('club').first() %}
{% set descendants = topEntry.getDescendants()  %}              
<ul>
    {% nav entry in descendants %}
        <li>
            {{ entry.title }} 
            {% ifchildren %}<ul>{% children %}</ul>{% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

how could I incorporate the cf_hideFromNav in this equation?

any help appreciated!
cheers
stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`descendantOf`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#descendantOf) parameter with a new ElementCriteriaModel instead of the [`getDescendants`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getDescendants) method on your entry model and you can add additional parameters. In your case add `cf_hideFromNav` as a parameter:

```
{% set topEntry = craft.entries.section('pages').slug('club').first() %}
{% set navItems = craft.entries.section('pages').descendantOf(topEntry).cf_hideFromNav('0') %}

{% nav navItem in navItems %}
    ...
{% endnav %}
```

You could also use the parameters [`id`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#id) or [`slug`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#slug) to exclude certain entries:

```
{% set topEntry = craft.entries.section('pages').slug('club').first() %}
{% set navItems = craft.entries.section('pages').descendantOf(topEntry).id('and, not 23, not 40, not 12') %}
```

The [`descendantOf`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#descendantOf) parameter also takes IDs. This would allow you to do this all with just a single ElementCriteriaModel:

```
{% set navItems = craft.entries.section('pages').descendantOf('1').id('and, not 23, not 40, not 12') %}
```

Comment: hi, that was exactly what I was after! but to my surprise it's not working!

Comment: this works: {% set navItems = craft.entries.section('pages').descendantOf(topEntry).cf_hideFromNav('1') %} -> it only shows the navItems that should not be displayed... but the other way round it doesn't work... bug?

Comment: but this works: {% set navItems = craft.entries.section('pages').descendantOf(topEntry).cf_hideFromNav('not 1') %} -> strange!

Comment: Nice you got it working, @outline4! Lightswitches write `0` to the DB if not active, so it's in fact strange!